# How can I hide show fields in Active Admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activeadmin, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am wondering if there is any way to hide fields in Active Admin on the show action or even not showing them if they are empty?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorted it in the .rb file for the resource -

```
  show :title => :Company_Name do
panel "COMPANY DETAILS" do
  attributes_table_for company, :Company_Name, :Title, :First_Name, :Surname, :Job_Title,:Direct_Number, :Contact_Email, :Address_1, :Address_2, :Address_3, :City, :Postcode, :Region, :Head_Office, :Showroom, :Trade_Counter, :Factory_Warehouse, :Telephone_Number, :Fax_Number, :Company_Email, :Web_Address, :PVCu_WindowsDoors_Method_1, :PVCu_WindowsDoors_System_1, :PVCu_WindowsDoors_Method_2, :PVCu_WindowsDoors_System_2, :Timber_Sash_Windows_Method, :FPW, :Composite_Doors_Method_1, :Composite_Doors_System_1, :Composite_Doors_Method_2, :Composite_Doors_System_2, :Composite_Doors_Method_3, :Composite_Doors_System_3, :Installer, :Trade, :Domestic, :Commercial, :New_Build 
end
active_admin_comments
```

end

Answer (score 0):

Just add a show blog with expected attributes in ActiveAdmin files, like following

```
 show do
   attributes_table do
     row :id
     row :title
     row :created_at
     row :updated_at        
   end
end
```